# about creating array with 0s and 1s, and making the content in random order

Tags: java, arrays

In java, what I should do the create an array with half of data is 0s, half 1s? And what I should do to use Randomize (shuffle) the contents of the array

Comment: Start by building array, adding 50% as `0` and 50% as `1`.  Then use `Collections.asList` and `Collections.shuffle` to randomise it

Comment: Do you mean *exactly* **half** of 0s and 1s?

Answer (score 2):

```
Integer[] arr = new Integer[100];
Arrays.fill(arr, 0, 50, 0);
Arrays.fill(arr, 50, 100, 1);
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(arr);
Collections.shuffle(list); //list is now in random order
```

If you want to avoid using a `Integer` and `List` for the sake of `Collections.shuffle()`, you'd need to implement the shuffling yourself. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519736/random-shuffling-of-an-array) question for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
int size = 100;
List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(0, size).mapToObj(x -> x).collect(Collectors.toList());
Collections.shuffle(list);
int[] result = list.stream().mapToInt(x -> x % 2).toArray();
```